# Как в posix shell проверить есть ли заданное словосочентание в строке?

Tags: shell

Есть строка и надо проверить есть ли в этой строке шаблонное словосочетание, как это сделать не на bash, а на shell(зависимость от платформы).
Написал на BASH, но на sh  не работает:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello world"

CONFIG=/etc/sys/config

if [[ "$CONFIG" = * "sys/config" * ]];then

echo success;

fi
```

Как это адаптировать под старый shell /bin/sh ?

Answer (score 1):

например, можно воспользоваться программой *grep*:

```
#/bin/sh

text="о сколько нам открытий чудных"
pattern1="нам открытий"
pattern2="нет открытий"

if echo "${text}" | grep -q "${pattern1}"; then
  echo "строка '${text}' содержит подстроку '{$pattern1}'"
else
  echo "строка '${text}' не содержит подстроку '${pattern1}'"
fi

if echo "${text}" | grep -q "${pattern2}"; then
  echo "строка '${text}' содержит подстроку '${pattern2}'"
else
  echo "строка '${text}' не содержит подстроку '${pattern2}'"
fi
```

результат выволнения:

```
строка 'о сколько нам открытий чудных' содержит подстроку 'нам открытий'
строка 'о сколько нам открытий чудных' не содержит подстроку 'нет открытий'
```

---

а можно и не порождать новый процесс, а воспользоваться возможностями [parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

```
#/bin/sh

text="о сколько нам открытий чудных"
pattern1="нам открытий"
pattern2="нет открытий"

if [ -z "${text##*${pattern1}*}" ]; then
  echo "строка '${text}' содержит подстроку '${pattern1}'"
else
  echo "строка '${text}' не содержит подстроку '${pattern1}'"
fi

if [ -z "${text##*${pattern2}*}" ]; then
  echo "строка '${text}' содержит подстроку '${pattern2}'"
else
  echo "строка '${text}' не содержит подстроку '${pattern2}'"
fi
```

результат выполнения аналогичный.